# Changing value in dataframe with the mean value based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that contains the mean of the price of each product:

{"Apple": 4.50, "Orange": 5.00, 'Banana': 2.00}

What I would like to do is to apply these mean values to rows in my DataFrame that contain a non valid (<=0) value in the "Price" column.

| ID | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 0 |
| 2 | Orange | -1 |
| 1 | Banana | -1 |
| 2 | Apple | 3.99 |

I tried to override/change the values by iterating (which I know isn't a good way to do this) and applying the mean value, but I am getting an error  SettingWithCopyWarning:

```
for i in df[df["Price"]<=0].index:
# Row location based on index
  df.loc[i]["Price"] = mean_prices_dict[df.loc[i]["Product"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) only for filtered rows:

```
d = {"Apple": 4.50, "Orange": 5.00, 'Banana': 2.00}

mask = df["Price"]<=0
df.loc[mask, 'Price'] = df.loc[mask, 'Product'].map(d)
print (df)
   ID Product  Price
0   1   Apple   4.50
1   2  Orange   5.00
2   1  Banana   2.00
3   2   Apple   3.99
```